# installing fedora 29 on a macbook medi 2011 with a radeon GPU

Tags: linux, fedora, macbook-pro, amd-radeon

I tried installing fedora 29 on my old MacBook Pro medio 2011 but as soon as i boot into it (during install from live usb) i get a white screen with loose pixels of all colors around the screen

the specs are :

```
Intel core i7-2760QM
Whistler[Radeaon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT]
```

I can provide extra hardware info if needed

p.s The same problem occurred when i tried it with fedora 28

Comment: The mouse is visible in the screen an can be moved

Comment: After installing OSX to check more specs i can conclude that OSX uses the integrated intel video card